# MS-SQL - Is it possible to manage the code of sql agent jobs using the Visual Studio SSDT plugin?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012, sql-server-data-tools

I have jobs in my DB held at server_agent/jobs.
Is there a way to manage them using ssdt plugin in Visual Studio 2012?
(Being able to Compare/Update)
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, there's no good way to handle this. Jobs are made up of data stored in the tables in msdb. The best way to handle it would be either to script out each job into its own file, then call those from one larger file or to make a single large file of all scripts for the jobs.

I'd probably look into scripting out each job into its own file and calling them from a larger script. It would be more manageable in the long term and you could easily comment out a single job by commenting it out of the main script.

There's no way to compare/update the jobs directly, though you could possibly use a Data Compare tool to check the various job tables in msdb against some master copy of the data. SQL Data Compare from Red-Gate is probably your best option for that as SSDT does not include data compare functionality at this time.

That being said, there are rumors that MS is working on some data-specific components for SSDT, but nothing official has been said about this capability.

Answer (score 1):

While there is no built-in support for managing SQL Agent Jobs directly in SSDT you can get deployment functionality using the Post-Deployment scripts

Granted this is not your question (sounds like you want to import, as well as compare, change)

However, you can put the "sql" of the job under source control, and deploy it (upsert) using either publish or indirectly with a built DACPAC

The gist is:
create a sql script which calls the msdb sp_xxx_job Stored Procedures

```
sp_add_job
sp_add_jobstep
sp_add_jobschedule
```

when using a script marked as a PostDeployment script invoke the job generation script

```
:r .\Jobs\MyPHATjob.sql
```